# Review on BoundView and UnboundView

Tags: ember.js

I would like to share the following snippet of a Bound/Unbound views to get feedback. Any suggestions will be welcome.

```
Yn.UnboundView = Em.View.extend({

  item: null,

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();
    this.$().text( this.get('item') );

  }

});


Yn.BoundView = Em.View.extend({

  item: null,

  render: function(buffer) {
    buffer.push( this.get('item') );
  },

  _itemDidChange: Ember.observer(function() {
    this.rerender();
  }, 'item')

});
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need sometimes to have an UnboundView or BoundView as a child of a more complex composite view.

Answer (score 1):

This is more idiomatic:

```
App.MyBoundView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Value: {{value}}'),
    valueBinding: 'App.myController.value'
});
```

Or unbound version:

```
App.MyUnboundView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Value: {{unbound value}}'),
    valueBinding: 'App.myController.value'
});
```

Or even:

```
App.MyOtherUnboundView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Value: {{unbound value}}'),
    value: 42
});
```

*Sample @ http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/GcUMu/*

Comment: That was my first approach, but then it came to my mind that perhaps we don't need a template for these cases.